# How to set value with selenium in RUBY program

Tags: html

I want to set like this

data-scene_cd="abc"

How can I do that with in  program?

HTML　is below one.

```
    <input id="bikeBox" type="text" class="input" data-scene_cd="" data-class_cd="" readonly="readonly">
    <input id="fourwdBox" type="text" class="fourwdBox input" data-fourwd_flg="0" readonly="readonly">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built in method of ruby: **execute_script** with a script to change element attribute.
ie:

```
 driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('data-scene_cd', 'abc');",[Element])
```

Attribute Change: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp

Execute Script Ruby: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/0.0.28/Selenium/WebDriver/Driver#execute_script-instance_method

Comment: Great !! I could do thanks to you. Thank you very much!